# How to filter based on friends of the logged in user?

Tags: python, django, leaderboard

I'm doing a leaderboard which it works when filtering from all users. But here I would like to filter based on the friends of the user.

This is how I get a list of friends :

```
users = self.request.user.friends
```

and this is my view :

```
class FriendsDayLeaderBoard(ListAPIView):
    """
    List friends Leaderboard based on XP token by Day

    Get request
    """
    serializer_class = UserLeaderboardSerializer
    queryset = UserLeaderboardTracking.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]


    def filter_queryset(self,queryset):
        users = self.request.user.friends
        return self.queryset.filter(created_at__date=timezone.now()) \
                            .values('user_id', 'user', 'day_streak') \
                            .annotate(xp_val=Sum('xp_value')) \
                            .order_by('-xp_val')[:20] \
```

UserLeaderboardTracking keeps track of all the users in the app every time they earn xp

tried to loop from a list of friends but not sure how to proceed in that direction

My model:

```
class UserLeaderboardTracking(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, related_name='user_leaderboard', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    xp_value = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    day_streak = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Can you show your model ?

Comment: Where do you want to "loop" friends? In a template or in a view or model?

Comment: In a model, like this : self.request.user.friends I get a list of friends of the logged in user. Not sure if I have to loop through it or that is an other way.

Comment: Now only the friends from the list I get should be filtered when I'm sorting in UserLeaderboardTracking and no all fo the users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter UserLeaderBoardTracking only for friends of current user, if i understood your post, you can do like this:

```py
class FriendsDayLeaderBoard(ListAPIView):
    """
    List friends Leaderboard based on XP token by Day

    Get request
    """
    serializer_class = UserLeaderboardSerializer
    queryset = UserLeaderboardTracking.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]


    def filter_queryset(self,queryset):
        users = self.request.user.friends
        queryset = queryset.filter(created_at__date=timezone.now())
        queryset = queryset.filter(user__in=users)
        queryset = queryset.values('user_id', 'user', 'day_streak')
        queryset = queryset.annotate(xp_val=Sum('xp_value'))
        queryset = queryset.order_by('-xp_val')[:20]

        return queryset
```